# "None of them... may not..."

Tags: grammar

I saw one sentence in a journal paper, which writes in the following manner:

> However, C. Duif presented in 2004 a review article [3] which argued that none of the external factors may not be the cause of such sudden changes.

Does it mean that none of the factors causes the changes, and the double negative serves as an emphasis?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's undoubtedly an error, though what the original should have been is impossible to determine.

Comment: "...that none of the external factors may not be the cause of such sudden changes" can be read as "...all of the external factors may be the cause of such sudden changes."

Comment: The best way to find out what he intended is to read the review article that's referenced as [3].

Comment: I suspect it is a bad translation of the French phrase "aucune...ne": Les filles sortent ce soir, mais **aucune ne** prend le train.The girls are going out tonight, but none (of them) are taking the train.

Answer (score 1):

I found the sentence in [this](https://www.scirp.org/html/3-4500094_26045.htm) article. The authors at the time were affiliated with astronomical observatories in Russia and Ukraine. The writing contains some non-idiomatic/ non-standard English, so I wouldn't focus too much on that one sentence, which seems like carelessness.

Examples:

> Many scientists remain at their opinion that...
>
> Moreover, the new attitude is growing that ...
>
> The observations were made with the instrument WEB_3, of which a basic
> description is given in [7].
>
> The fact was very interesting that the torsion balance graph during
> the eclipse had a tendency to decrease.